# Check if object exist and has property

Tags: php

How can i get something prettier than condition inside condition?

```
$permission = $user->permissions; //return object with permissions
 if ($permission) {
     if (!$permission->can_edit) {
         throw Errors::exception(Errors::PERMISSION_DENIED);
     }
 }
```

Comment: You could use an AND (&&)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Why not ensure that `$user->permissions` always contains an object, such that you can skip the first check

Comment: Also, something like `if ($permission)` should better be written as `if($permission instanceof Class)`, to ensure that this **reallly** holds an object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can merge your 2 if in the same :

```
$permission = $user->permissions; //return object with permissions
 if ($permission && !$permission->can_edit){
         throw Errors::exception(Errors::PERMISSION_DENIED);
 }
```

Because if `$permission` was false or empty ( not exist ) php not execute the following test `!$permission->can_edit` then u don't have errors, and you write 1 if.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this if it works.

```
if(!property_exists($permission, 'can_edit')){
    throw Errors::exception(Errors::PERMISSION_DENIED);
}
```

Comment: What is "this"? Your code works completely different

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it